# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, boolean, elementtree

I'm trying to install CESM2 and while trying to create a new case I receive this error:

> ```
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse  tree.parse(source, parser)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
>
> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 211, column 2
> ```

When I traced back line 211 in ElementTree.py, it contains this function:

```py
def __bool__(self):
    warnings.warn(
        "The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  "
        "Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.",
        FutureWarning, stacklevel=2
        )
    return len(self._children) != 0 # emulate old behaviour, for now
```

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: "while trying to create a new case": What does that mean?

Comment: I'm trying to run CESM2 model and for that I have to create a case using particular component set. But I realized I get the same error while I tried to run scripts_regression_test.py interactively.

Comment: I don't know what a "case" or a "component set" is, but somehow an XML document is parsed. However, the XML is not well-formed and therefore you get an error. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22junk+after+document+element%22+python for other questions related to the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The indicated position (*line 211, column 2*) refers to the **source** file
being parsed, not the line in your code.

When parsing XML file, it should contain a **single** element at the top level.
Apparently your source XML is malformed.

Sometimes a solution in this case is to "wrap" the whole content with
a single "root" element.
At least this parsing error should disappear, but note that it changes the
output XML tree, compared to the original intention, so maybe some XPath expressions should be also changed.